# hit google analytics on sign in of my android application

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

How to fetch google analytic, when  user login in my android application, am now able to get the analytics after coming in the home screen, I want the application to hit when user login to my android application.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Google-analytics` code in login page. You can put "google-analytics code", in successful login condition.

Please refer [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#activity-or-fragment) link:

Use this piece of code in your successful login condition:

// Obtain the shared Tracker instance.

```
AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + name);
mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```